# Clear content in specific cell using Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have write app script as below, I am stuck with this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')"

```
function clearContent() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Filter Tools")
  var r1 = ss.getRange(['F3:F6'])
  var r2 = ss.getRange(['H2']) 
  r1.clearContent();
  r2.clearContent();
 
}

function onEdit (e){
if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "F2"){clearContent()
}
}
```

please help fix the script

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. If you're running onEdit() from the console it won't work since it's supposed to be triggered only by modifications in the cells. Try changing F2
2. Could you try removing the brackets inside .getRange()? ss.getRange('F3:F6') and ss.getRange('H2')
3. Try only running clearContent() from the console and share what error it throws if any left.

Let us know!